Android Azure Chat SDK - Push-notifications has no data
I'm integrating Azure Chat SDK for Android in my project following this guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/tutorials/chat-android-push-notification
My issue is that while I can receive push-notification in onMessageReceived#FirebaseMessagingService, I cannot access the data. There's something inside the message, but mosty gibberish kind of data - not what I'd expect such as title/content.
The RemoteMessage.notification is null. What I do is:
if (remoteMessage.data.isNotEmpty()) {
    val chatPushNotification = ChatPushNotification()
        .setPayload(remoteMessage.data)

         notificationManager.azureChatNotificationReceived(
             "New Chat Message",
             "You Just Received A New Message!",
             chatPushNotification
         )
}

Obviously, I want to achieve and extract data at this moment (get the content of message and sender). To me it feels like the message that is sent is configured in a way that is not suitable for RemoteNotification and that is causing weird formatting.

Additional information - I know that from Azure Notification Hub I can send "test message" and that allows any formatting I want, however, I'm interested is there any way I can fix formatting when a new chat message is sent? Feels to me, that is controlled by Azure itself? If it can be done - where?
P.S. Sometimes I also receive following error (it comes from the ChatPushNotification).
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to parse push notification payload: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid encrypted push notification payload. Dropped the request!


Issue is still open and not resolved!
